# Theory behind certificate for job account

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, java, pkcs12

I made it work a job account protected by a certificate in a java spring application but is not that clear to me the minimal steps.(Could you believe that :) I need some theory. 
Here my steps:

- get the certificate of format pkcs12
- install the certificate on my windows7 machine(Installed in trusted root)
- checking existing entries of .p12 and their alias (keytool -list -   
  keystore...)
- Export the public key first (keytool -exportcert -keystore...)
- Import it to cacerts (keytool -importcert -keystore...)
- Then I received an error like my machine and the server didn't trust    
      themselves
- Access server, and retrieve certificate(java InstallCert ...)
- In my application I set properties for pkcs12 file password and truestStore

What's the role of installing the certificate on my machine? Is it necessary.